# Simulating constraint ON UPDATE option by TRIGGER

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to simulate ON UPDATE option in my foreign keys by making trigger that will update child records after update.

Trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SOMETABLE_AU_ID_TRG
  AFTER UPDATE OF ID ON SOMETABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE SOMECHILDTABLE SET SOMETABLE_ID = :NEW.ID WHERE ID = :OLD.ID;
END;
```

And I'm making the child table constraint deferrable like this:

```
set constraint 
SOMECHILDTABLE_FK_SOMETABLE deferred;
```

But it still gives me `ORA-02292 (child record found)` on commit. How can I avoid this?

Comment: I think you need to change the `WHERE` clause to something like `WHERE SOMETABLE_ID = :OLD.ID`.  It didn't show up in @APC's example because `SOMETABLE_ID` and `ID` contained the same values.  However, there are pitfalls with trying to cascade updates using a trigger that you should consider, like those discussed at http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5773459616034.

Answer (score 2):

Kudos to @BrianCamire for spotting the bug:

Let's start by creating your trigger...

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SOMETABLE_AU_ID_TRG
  AFTER UPDATE OF ID ON SOMETABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE SOMECHILDTABLE SET SOMETABLE_ID = :NEW.ID WHERE ID = :OLD.ID;
END;  2    3    4    5    6  
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> alter table somechildtable add constraint some_fk foreign key (sometable_id)
  2  references sometable (id) deferrable initially deferred;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Here is the data ...

```
SQL> select * from somechildtable;

        ID SOMETABLE_ID
---------- ------------
        11            1
        12            2
        13            6
        14            4
        15            5

SQL>
```

So, let's mess with the parent data....

```
SQL> update sometable set id = 3 where id = 6
  2  /

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;
commit
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (APC.SOME_FK) violated - child record found


SQL>
```

Aha!  So, as Brian says we need to change the trigger code:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SOMETABLE_AU_ID_TRG
      AFTER UPDATE OF ID ON SOMETABLE
      FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      UPDATE SOMECHILDTABLE SET SOMETABLE_ID = :NEW.ID WHERE SOMETABLE_ID = :OLD.ID;
    END; 
/

  2    3    4    5    6    7  
Trigger created.

SQL> SQL> update sometable set id = 3 where id = 6;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from somechildtable
  2  /

        ID SOMETABLE_ID
---------- ------------
        11            1
        12            2
        13            3
        14            4
        15            5

SQL>
```